# Unable to do any install, upgrade, ... using apt

Tags: apt

Did complete reinstall of Elementary OS 6.0 and so far so good.  After installing, upgrading, ...
all the necessary packages i was pretty content with it.

Since last week Apt is mentioning that it can't find any repositories anymore, so no install via apt is possible anymore, which is pretty annoying.  I have been looking all over the internet to find a solution and tried even adding some other links to the sources.list but nothing helps.

```
tim@Korafola:/etc$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=6
DISTRIB_CODENAME=odin
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 6 Odin"

tim@Korafola:/etc$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 6.0 _odin_ - stable amd64 (20211103)]/ focal contrib main non-free
#deb http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

  tim@Korafola:/etc$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist [102 B]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:6 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/quiterss/quiterss/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:6 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
Hit:11 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise InRelease
Ign:5 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-security InRelease
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports Release
Ign:7 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-security InRelease
Ign:13 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise Release
Ign:14 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-updates Release
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release
Ign:12 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-backports Release
Err:13 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.111.204.131 80]
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security Release
Err:12 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates Release
Ign:15 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-security Release
Err:14 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu precise-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.111.204.131 80]
Err:15 http://mirror.unix-solutions.be/ubuntu precise-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Hit:16 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Odin is based on Ubuntu Focal (20.04) but for some reason you have Precise repos added to the system (which is I believe Ubuntu 12.04).

Remove all references to Precise in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

EDIT:

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Comment: True but only half an answer. The OP not only needs to remove all the lines referencing `precise` but they *also* need to replace them with lines referencing the Elementary repos. (I do not have an Elementary 6.0 machine to say what these should be, though.)

Comment: that's what I thought.  I only wonder how the precise keyword got there in the first place.  I never put it there.  ANyway, what should I put in place for Elementary repos?